KendoReact - How to pass 'title' metadata value to ExcelExport component
In KendoReact, I can modify the Author metadata value to whatever I want it to be by simply passing a creator prop to it. The outputted excel file will reflect the desired Author in it's metadata.
For accessibility purposes, I (along with anyone else working with accessibility) need to be able to modify the Title metadata value in order that a screen reader can orient and guide a non-sighted user.
Any idea how this can be done?
Image of the file's Properties dialog box
I stepped through the code to see if I could "catch" the file before it was downloaded, that way I could modify the metadata via the ExcelJS npm package, but I cannot get a hold of the file before it is downloaded. I also tried creating a wrapper that could accept a title prop, but without the functionality within the ExcelExport component, I'm up the creek. I was expecting to be able to pass a title prop to the ExcelExport component.

It doesn't seem that this functionality exists within Kendo. I have created a feature request with Kendo Accessibility - Modify Export Output PropTypes to include title. Please upvote it.
